# I want to use a checkbox to mark todos as completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, event-handling

Iam currently working in reactjs with a todo list app. Where I need to implement a new function for completing todo tasks and then later on filtering them by status.

I have some issues with my checkbox function.

It doesn't specify a noteID. for example I can check noteID 4 to be completed and then list the notes by ascending, and suddenly noteID 1 is checked because it took noteIDs 4 spot.

Checkbox status value is not saving in the database also when checking a task and refreshing the page it unchecks by itself.

Part of my code:

```
const [Status2, setStatus2] = useState(false);
const handleStatus = (event, data) => {
console.log("Marking todo ... Data : ", data);
setStatus2(true);
  };
```

Checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
style={{ flex: 1 }}
onChange={handleStatus}
/>
```

Status2 is supposed to be a completed status boolean for the todos.

Comment: Here is full code: https://pastebin.com/TCY3Aq37

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you're using the `index` as a unique key in your `.map` function for rendering TODOs:

````
           NoteData.map(function (data, index) {
              return (
                <div className="Data-flex" key={index}>
    ```

You should replace that `key` prop with a value unique to all IDs, like `data.noteId`:
````

````
       NoteData.map(function (data, index) {
          return (
            <div className="Data-flex" key={data.noteId}>
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped my checkbox mark and when changing the order (asc/desc) it stays on the same note. But the problem is still however that it's not saving to the database and also whenever I refresh the page checkbox vanishes.